# Javascript graph skeleton implementation

Tags: javascript, graph

I started implementing a graph drawing application in javascript and < canvas > element, and i just wanted to hear your thought on the progress so far. I'm very open to suggestions and i'm very interested to hear what you have to say.
So you can see the progress so far in the present code, if you have any questions about it feel free to ask.

```
var graph = {

init: function(edges) {
    graph.vertices = {};
    graph.edges = {};
    graph.canvas = document.getElementById('platno');
    graph.width = graph.canvas.width;
    graph.height = graph.canvas.height;
    graph.hookes_test = true;
    graph.ctx = graph.canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", graph.klik, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", graph.drop, false);
    document.addEventListener("dblclick", graph.dblclick, false);
    graph.addNodesFromEdgesList(edges);
    graph.addEdgesFromEdgesList(edges);
    graph.mapEdges(graph.oDuljina);
    setInterval(graph.draw, 1024 / 24);
},
addNodesFromEdgesList: function(EdgesList) {
    for (var r1 = 0; r1 < EdgesList.length; r1++) {
        for (var r2 = 0; r2 < EdgesList[r1].length - 1; r2++) {

            if ((typeof graph.vertices[EdgesList[r1][r2]]) === "undefined") {
                graph.addNode({
                    id: EdgesList[r1][r2],
                    x: Math.floor(graph.width / 2 + 100 * Math.cos(Math.PI * (EdgesList[r1][r2] * 2) / 11)),
                    y: Math.floor(graph.height / 2 + 100 * Math.sin(Math.PI * (EdgesList[r1][r2] * 2 / 11))),
                    size: 6,
                    ostalo: 100
                });
            }
        }
    }
},
addEdgesFromEdgesList: function(EdgesList) {
    for (var a = 0; a < EdgesList.length; a++) {
        graph.addEdge({
            from: EdgesList[a][0],
            to: EdgesList[a][1],
            id: a
        });
    }
},
node: function(node) {
    this.id = node.id;
    this.pos = new vektor(node.x, node.y);
    this.size = node.size;
    this._size = node.size;
    this.expanded = false;
},
addNode: function(node) {
    (typeof graph.vertices[node.id]) === "undefined" ? graph.vertices[node.id] = new graph.node(node) : console.log("Duplikat cvora! Id:" + node.id);
},
removeNode: function(id) {
    if (typeof graph.vertices[id] !== "undefined") {
        graph.removeEdgeByNodeId(id);
        if (id == graph.info_node.id) graph.info_node = false;
        delete graph.vertices[id];
    } else {
        console.log("Ne postoji node! Id:" + id);
    }
},
edge: function(edge) {
    this.id = edge.id;
    this.from = graph.vertices[edge.from];
    this.to = graph.vertices[edge.to];
},
addEdge: function(edge) {
    (typeof graph.edges[edge.id]) === "undefined" ? graph.edges[edge.id] = new graph.edge(edge) : console.log("Duplikat brida! Id:" + edge.id);
},
removeEdgeByEdgeId: function(id) {
    (typeof graph.edges[id]) !== "undefined" ? delete graph.edges[id] : console.log("Ne postoji brid! Id:" + id);
},
removeEdgeByNodeId: function(id) {
    if (typeof graph.vertices[id] !== "undefined") {
        for (var edge in graph.edges) {
            if (graph.edges.hasOwnProperty(edge) && (graph.edges[edge].from.id == id || graph.edges[edge].to.id == id)) {
                delete graph.edges[edge];
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Ne postoji cvor! Id:" + id);
    }

},
clearGraph: function() {
    for (var id in graph.vertices) {
        if (graph.vertices.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            graph.removeNode(id)
        }
    }
},
mapNodes: function(funkcija, obj) {
    var res = [],
        tmp, id;
    for (id in graph.vertices) {
        if (graph.vertices.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            tmp = funkcija.apply(graph, [graph.vertices[id], obj || {}]);
            if (tmp) res.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    return res;
},
mapEdges: function(funkcija) {
    for (var id in graph.edges) {
        if (graph.edges.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            funkcija.apply(graph, [graph.edges[id].from, graph.edges[id].to, graph.edges[id].id]);
        }
    }
},
vuci: function(e) {

    if (graph.drag) {
        graph.drag.pos.x = (e.pageX - graph.canvas.offsetLeft);
        graph.drag.pos.y = (e.pageY - graph.canvas.offsetTop);
        if (graph.drag.pos.x > graph.width - 6) graph.drag.pos.x = graph.width - 6;
        else if (graph.drag.pos.x < 6) graph.drag.pos.x = 6;
        else if (graph.drag.pos.y > graph.height - 6) graph.drag.pos.y = graph.height - 6;
        else if (graph.drag.pos.y < 6) graph.drag.pos.y = 6;
    }

},

klik: function(e) {

    graph.drag = graph.getNodeFromXY(e.pageX - graph.canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - graph.canvas.offsetTop)[0];
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", graph.vuci, false);
},
drop: function() {
    graph.drag = false;
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", graph.vuci, false);
},
getNodeFromXY: function(_x, _y) {

    return graph.mapNodes(function(node, obj) {
        if ((obj.x > node.pos.x - node.size) && (obj.x < node.pos.x + node.size) && (obj.y > node.pos.y - node.size) && (obj.y < node.pos.y + node.size)) {
            return node;
        } else {
            return false
        };

    }, {
        x: _x,
        y: _y
    });

},
draw: function() {

    graph.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, graph.width, graph.height);
    background();
    graph.mapEdges(crtaj_v);
    graph.mapNodes(crtaj_n);
    graph.info();
    if (!graph.hookes_test) graph.mapEdges(graph.hookes);

    function background() {
        var grd = graph.ctx.createRadialGradient(graph.width / 2, graph.height / 2, 30, graph.width / 2, graph.height / 2, graph.height);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "#42586d");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#36495a");
        grd.addColorStop(1, "#26323e");
        graph.ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        graph.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, graph.width, graph.height);

    }

    function crtaj_n(v) {
        graph.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
        graph.ctx.beginPath();
        graph.ctx.arc(v.pos.x, v.pos.y, v.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        graph.ctx.fill();
        graph.ctx.strokeStyle = '#818f9a'
        graph.ctx.arc(v.pos.x, v.pos.y, v.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        graph.ctx.stroke();
        return false;
    }

    function crtaj_v(v1, v2) {
        graph.ctx.beginPath();
        graph.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rga(129,143,154,0.1)';
        var duljina = [v1.pos.udaljenost(v2.pos) - v1.size, v1.pos.udaljenost(v2.pos) - v2.size];
        var kut = Math.atan2(v2.pos.y - v1.pos.y, v2.pos.x - v1.pos.x);
        graph.ctx.moveTo(v2.pos.x - (duljina[0] * Math.cos(kut)), v2.pos.y - (duljina[0] * Math.sin(kut)));
        graph.ctx.lineTo(v1.pos.x + (duljina[1] * Math.cos(kut)), v1.pos.y + (duljina[1] * Math.sin(kut)));
        graph.ctx.stroke();
    }

},

dblclick: function(e) {
    var dbl = graph.getNodeFromXY(e.pageX - platno.offsetLeft, e.pageY - platno.offsetTop)[0] || false;
    if (dbl.expanded) {
        dbl.size = dbl._size;
        dbl.expanded = false;
        graph.info_node = false;
    } else if (dbl) {
        graph.mapNodes(function(v1) {
            if (v1.expanded) {
                v1.size = v1._size;
                v1.expanded = false;
                graph.info_node = false;
            }
        })
        dbl.size = 30;
        dbl.expanded = true;
        graph.info_node = dbl;
    }
},
info: function() {
    if (graph.info_node) {
        graph.ctx.font = "10px Verdana";
        graph.ctx.textAlign = "center";
        graph.ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        graph.ctx.fillText("Node: " + graph.info_node.id, graph.info_node.pos.x, graph.info_node.pos.y + 3, 30);
    }

},
hookes: function(v1, v2, id) {
    var duljina = v1.pos.oduzmi(v2.pos),
        udaljenost = duljina.duljina() - (graph.edges[id].duljina),
        HL = 20 * (udaljenost / duljina.duljina()),
        kut = Math.atan2(v2.pos.y - v1.pos.y, v2.pos.x - v1.pos.x);
    (graph.drag && (graph.drag.id != v1.id)) || !graph.drag ? graph.zbrojiLokacija(v1, kut, HL) : false;
    (graph.drag && (graph.drag.id != v2.id)) || !graph.drag ? graph.oduzmiLokacija(v2, kut, HL) : false;

},
oDuljina: function(v1, v2, id) {
    graph.hookes_test = false;
    graph.edges[id].duljina = v1.pos.oduzmi(v2.pos).duljina();
},
zbrojiLokacija: function(v1, kut, HL) {
    var dis = new vektor(HL * Math.cos(kut), HL * Math.sin(kut))
    if (v1.pos.x + dis.x > graph.width - v1.size || v1.pos.x + dis.x < 0 + v1.size) {
        v1.pos.x += dis.x * (-1);
        v1.pos.y += dis.y;
    } else if (v1.pos.y + dis.y > graph.height - v1.size || v1.pos.y + dis.y < 0 + v1.size) {
        v1.pos.x += dis.x;
        v1.pos.y += dis.y * (-1);
    } else {
        v1.pos = v1.pos.zbroji(dis)
    }
},

oduzmiLokacija: function(v1, kut, HL) {
    var dis = new vektor(HL * Math.cos(kut), HL * Math.sin(kut))
    if (v1.pos.x + dis.x > graph.width - v1.size || v1.pos.x + dis.x < 0 + v1.size) {
        v1.pos.x -= dis.x * (-1);
        v1.pos.y -= dis.y;
    } else if (v1.pos.y + dis.y > graph.height - v1.size || v1.pos.y + dis.y < 0 + v1.size) {
        v1.pos.x -= dis.x;
        v1.pos.y -= dis.y * (-1);
    } else {
        v1.pos = v1.pos.oduzmi(dis)
    }
}

}

function vektor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
vektor.prototype.zbroji = function(v1) {
    return new vektor(this.x + v1.x, this.y + v1.y);
}
vektor.prototype.oduzmi = function(v1) {
    return new vektor(this.x - v1.x, this.y - v1.y);
}

vektor.prototype.division = function(x) {
    return new vektor(this.x / x, this.y / x);
}

vektor.prototype.multiply = function(x) {
    return new vektor(this.x * x, this.y * x);
}

vektor.prototype.udaljenost = function(v1) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v1.x - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(v1.y - this.y, 2));
}

vektor.prototype.duljina = function() {
    return Math.max(20, Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y, 2)));
}
//////////////////////////////////////
//  Test data                       //
/////////////////////////////////////
var edges = [
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [3, 4, 1],
    [3, 5, 1],
    [3, 6, 1],
    [4, 1, 1],
    [4, 2, 1],
    [5, 6, 1]
    ];
graph.init(edges);
```

UPDATE: added new code, this is just a preview i didn't have time to optimize the code, and also some of function names and varibles are written in my native language.

Also I've added a jsfiddle link so you can see the work so far in action.
http://jsfiddle.net/nNcHJ/1/

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example of using it?

Comment: @Muha An example would be good. I would also start from the API, how would you expect the user to enter the values of a graph. Say you were to define a Traveling Salesman problem? See https://github.com/ajaxorg/apf/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS for a good style guide

Comment: @Muha Thanks, you will get a better review, if you translate some of the code to English, `klik` and `vektor` are fine but what is `zbrojiLokacija`? (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). In general though it is shaping up and looks interesting. Also you need to change the canvas size in the jsFiddle in order to see it say 300px x 300px.

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback, i'm planning to convert the names but i didn't have plenty of time today. but i will get to it soon.

Comment: I would consider using a library to help abstract out some of the Canvas stuff you are doing. I haven't done anything on Canvas yet, but when I used to do stuff like this I would use http://raphaeljs.com/. (Generates SVG).

Comment: Hello @Travis i'm doing this as a personal project so i can better learn have to use Javasript, so when i get a hang of it i'll definitely use a library, because of the performance that they give.

Comment: @Muha, that makes sense, good luck :)

Comment: @Muha There's a design issue that got to my attention as soon as I started to look at the code. You should definitely make use of `this` instead of `graph` at multiple places. Also, your object is making too many assumptions, things such as the canvas id shouldn't be hard-coded within the *class*.

Comment: Also you have far too many property lookups; they are expensive in JS. Instead of repeating things like `graph.ctx` multiple times, store the value in a variable and use that variable to reference your object. You should as well stick to a single naming convention, you are using *under_score*, *UpperCaseCamel*, *lowerCaseCamel* ... that's too much.

Answer (score 2):

I like the code on the whole, I could work with this.
My 2 cents:

- `graph.hookes_test` , please use lowerCaseCamel, so `graph.hookTest`
- `graph.oDuljina` , please use English
- `document.getElementById('platno');` , if you provide an options parameter to `init(edges)`, then you can write something like `document.getElementById( options.canvasID || 'platno');`
- `setInterval(graph.draw, 1024 / 24);` , put magical numbers together in a section, preferably with a comment as to what the value means, consider to have this overridable by `options` as well.
- You have `this.size = node.size;` and also `this._size = node.size;`, whatever problem you solve with this should probably be addressed differently
- `typeof graph.vertices[node.id]) === "undefined"` probably deserves its own one line function, `nodeExists()`, you use that expression all over the place
- `clearGraph`, why can you not simply either re-`init()` or set `vertices` and `edges` to {} ?
- in `vuci` , the magical constant 6 should be a `var`
- in `draw` and `info` , you should have a `var` section with all your style info